# Apply already loaded js in index.html to routed html page in SPA in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to apply js loaded in index.html to new template loaded using route inside ng-view.

```
<script src="/static/core/js/custom.js"></script>
```

here is custom.js which i have loaded in my index.html.
And this is my router

```
.when('/admin/core/user/add/', {
    templateUrl : '/static/templates/create_user.html',
    controller : 'userController',
})
```

so, whenever I am going to load create_user.html in my ng-view of index.html it can't get any effect from custom.js

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you mean. What is "apply js of index.html"? Do you want to load a javascript file upon each state?

Comment: What do you mean *apply js*? Can you share sample code or describe the problem in detail? I think you have some problem which is likely to be resolved by using a directive.

Comment: I have loaded some js files in my index.html and when i include some html file using ng-view, on newly added html file i can't get any effect from that js file. So is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Whether you should do it or not is another question.

Comment: How it is possible @dfsq

Comment: Well, there are some ways: 1. Hook into `ngView` `$viewContentLoaded` or 'onload' events. 2. Mutation observers. I would go with the first. The second is simpler, but it's IE11+ support. UPD. Well actually the first way is super simple too.

Comment: I am new to angularjs so can you please give more light on it??

Comment: I could. What exactly do you want to do. Clarify the question first. So you have some script that you want to do what when ngView is reloaded?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112772/discussion-between-dharmik-and-dfsq).

Comment: Describe briefly so that I could give you a solution.

Comment: One question: what does `custom.js` would do to ngView content? For example?

Comment: Like an example it is giving me count of table content selected and toggle my div etc..

Comment: Okay, I'm posing an answer with the demo, you should be able to figure out what you need from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can hook to `ngView` onload event. Demo first:

```js
angular.module('demo', ['ngRoute'], function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/one', { template: 'One template' })
    .when('/two', { template: 'Two template' })
})

.run(function($rootScope, $route) {
  $rootScope.__loaded = function() {
    window.updateView($route.current);
  };
});

// Some global script that does something to content loaded into <ng-view>
function updateView(route) {
  document.querySelector('#ng-view').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
    <div><small>Hacked from outside: ${route.originalPath}</small></div>
  `);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular-route.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo">

  <a href="#/one">One</a>  <a href="#/two">Two</a>

  <div>
    <ng-view id="ng-view" onload="__loaded()"></ng-view>
  </div>

</div>
```

So the idea is that you specify event handler on the `$rootScope` (or root controller $scope, doesn't matter). Then from inside of this handler you simply invoke whatever global function you want. That global function can then make whatever DOM manipulations it needs to do with ngView content.

Comment: bingo, It worked thaks a lot.....